# Combined lookup and embed in the same MongoDB collection depending on root document structure

Tags: mongodb, join

I want to make a conditional lookup with Mongo in the following way: a root document contains either a link (`customerId`) to the `customers` collection or directly embeds a customer, like this:

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "item": "item1",
  "customer": { _id: 1, "name": "Jane Doe" }
},
{
   "_id":  2,
   "item": "item2",
   "customerId": 1
}
```

customers collection:

```
{ _id: 1, "name": "Jane Johnson" }
```

The `customers` collection stores the current versions of customers; to maintain consistency, members of the `items` collection will contain just ids of customer. But if I want to freeze an item so it holds *the* version of its customer at a certain time, I will embed that `customer` directly into the `item` in question.

When searching for `items` I want them to appear uniformly (i.e. regardless whether customer is looked up or embedded it will appear as embedded field):
e.g.

```
[{
  "_id" : 1,
  "item": "item1",
  "customer": { _id: 1, "name": "Jane Doe" } // historical version of Jane (embedded)
},
{
   "_id":  2,
   "item": "item2",
   "customer": { _id: 1, "name": "Jane Johnson" } // current version of Jane by lookup
}]
```

Question 1: is this the right approach and if not what is the best practice for handling cases like this? 
Question 2: if my approach is correct, how to best use aggregation framework to achieve this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answers:

1. Yes, you can achieve it with [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and it is one of the possible solutions (the other possible solution would be to implement it in your program).
2. Just use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/looku) (for data merging from other collection) and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) (for final result generation) pipeline stages.

Query example:

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "customers",
            localField: "customerId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "customerData"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "item": 1,
            "customer": {
                $cond: {
                    if: {$gt: [{$size: "$customerData"}, 0]},
                    then: {$arrayElemAt: ["$customerData", 0]},
                    else: "$customer"
                }
            }
       }
    }
]);
```